# "I've never used to before", is it right form?

Tags: grammar, phrases

"I've never used to before", is it right form? I wanna know how to say when something that didn't enjoy at previous time.

Answer (score 2):

"Never used to" can be a correct grammatical form if you are referring to something that over and over in the past was not the case but now it is. For example

> I never used to experience pain when running, but now that I'm older, even a short jog hurts a lot.

You would not normally use this form if it is still the case that you never experience pain.

Unfortunately you don't give quite enough context in your question for me to know whether this is a correct form for *your* situation.  If you add a bit more information about what you want to say I may be able to help more.

Comment: Please review the ELL rules about "proofreading" questions, or questions which are very light on detail.   Rather than answer these kind of questions, let the user know they need to add more detail to avoid having the question closed.

Comment: I did request more info but I also gave has much help as I could, which is what I think is best.  Respectfully, I do not agree with your stated philosophy on how to handle this situation.

Comment: Sure, I think that's normal with people new to this site who just want to help out.  I think your attitude tends to shift once you've been around for a while and understand how questions without details are of little use to the next person searching for the same answer.   It's better to have questions and answers which apply to a wide audience.

Answer (score -1):

It is not correct. If you were asked "Do you like coffee?" you might reply "I never used to [but I do now because...]"